# Length of a line to the surface of a sphere when line does not originate from center

Tags: linear-algebra, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, spheres

Finding Length of a line to the surface of a sphere when line does not originate from center.

Here is what I know:

- I have a `3D` sphere of radius $7$
- I have a line (call it `line1`) with a known polar and azimuthal angle leaving a point that is shifted from the center/origin $(x_0, y_0, z+0.4)$.
- I am trying to determine the distance from the point of origin of `line1` to the surface of the sphere.

I had a triangle built that with law of sines worked, but I am realizing the angle in this triangle ($\phi$) should be dependent on both azimuth and polar so am not sure how to get this angle any more. Initially I assumed this angle was just a function of polar (i. e. $90^\circ$-polar) but this only works if azimuthal in along the $z$-axis in the diagram.
[image]

Comment: I can't make sense of the first "not" in the title

Comment: Sorry just fixed title to hopefully make more sense

Comment: I don't know what the point of origin of a line is, but if the line does not intersect the sphere then dist(line, sphere) = dist(line, center of sphere) - radius.

Comment: First parametrize the line as $\vec{r}(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t))$, then plug $x(t), y(t), z(t)$ into the equation of your sphere and solve for $t$. Evaluating $\vec{r}(t)$ at this value for $t$ will give the intersection point between the line and the sphere, which is what you need to compute the distance.